# Eclipse plugin for Java project to report all errors in project? Error report generator?

Tags: java, eclipse, report

I have imported a series of Java source files into a standard Eclipse Java project. Of course, it is reporting missing dependencies of JAR files? Is there an Eclipse plugin or feature that summarize all of these build errors of the project into one report? I would just like to summarize it into one spot.
Thanks

Comment: Doesn't Eclipse already do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Window -> Show View -> Problems`

And there you get many options to customize the view.